# How to redraw GTK# widget

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk#

How i can redraw or repaint window or widget?
For example in Java Swing I can use repaint() and validate() .

```
using System;
using Gtk;
namespace Road111
{
    public partial class TransportDialog1 : Gtk.Dialog
    {
        public TransportDialog1()
        {
            Build();
        }
        protected void Refresh_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           If(....)
       //refresh_command
        protected void Ok_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           thi.Hide();
        }

        protected void Cancel_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try Gtk.Widget  `queue_draw`. Not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: The `QueueDraw()` method redraws the widget. I'm pretty sure calling `QueueDraw()` on a container redraws all the children widgets.